# mach_inject and mach_override sample code?

Tags: mach

Does anybody have any sample working code working for OSX 10.6 or more using `mach_inject` and `mach_override`? I am trying to inject code into finder for adding my own contextual menu item using `mach_inject`. I would like to have some see sample working code? If anybody have any other suggestions, they are welcome as well.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm also searching currently for that.

Comment: I did not figure out totally.. but trying my way in!

Comment: Did you found any working sample?

Comment: This is a great example and looks promising: http://www.aorensoftware.com/blog/2011/12/24/death-to-ds_store/, but I can't find the function and place, that needs to be overwritten.

Comment: I am able to inject my bundle into Finder process and made it execute inside finder process. Now I am looking for method which needs to be overridden to achieve the context menu. I already overrode some methods and trying few more. There is no documentation as such for which methods to be overridden. So I m in trial and error mode.

Comment: BTW, I used method swizzling over mach_override.

Comment: Thank you. If you figure our the method to override, would be nice to share it, will save much time of other developers :)

Comment: @Sarvesh can you please share some sample code? :-)

Comment: @Sarvesh Can you please share a sample code. Really will help us :)